# Trying to use bearer token but unable to use firstordefault method in account controller for applicationuser table.(need tocheck user is admin or not)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

[image]

In account controller need to check whether user is admin or not using custom property isadmin in bearer token authentication using dot net webapi.

```
public bool Isadmin(string username,string password)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    //or default        
}
```

Comment: Have you import [Linq namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0) by `using System.Linq`?

Comment: Thanks i miss namespace problem solved.

Comment: Note that you can click on a type name and press `Ctrl` + `.` on your keyboard (or right-click and select "Quick actions and refactoring") and it will prompt you to add the appropriate `using`.